# Автоматический переводчик выделенного текста Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, bash

Всем привет, написал не большую программу и скрипт для вывода перевода в всплывающие уведомления.
Работает все хорошо только когда выделяю большой текст перевод полностью не помещается в уведомление помогите это исправить!) Хочу чтобы текст в уведомлении высвечивался полностью **без.......**

## [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Программа:**

```
from googletrans import Translator
import sys

translator = Translator()
c = sys.argv[1]

def test(a):

    b = translator.translate(a,dest='ru')
    return b.text

x = test(str(c))
print(x)
```

**Скрипт:**

```
#!/bin/bash

text=`xsel -o`

translated=`python3 /home/unknow/translete/translate.py "$text"`

run=`echo $translated`

notify-send "$run"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**zenity** решил мой вопрос

```
#!/bin/bash

text=`xsel -o`

translated=`python3 /home/unknow/translete/translate.py "$text"`

run=`echo $translated`

zenity --info --title="Перевод" --text "$run" --width=600
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]